# I need to 'wp_dequeue_script' and 'styles' and ADD a bunch of other css and js

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

Here's what I am trying to achieve: I have to make a template which does NOT require any of the theme's (main theme's) css and js except for the bootstrap css framework.

My question is this: I'd like to know if this ruleset in my functions.php is valid:

```
if ( is_page_template( 'specific-template.php' ) ) {
    //  Remove CSS 1
    wp_dequeue_style( 'generic styles 1' );
    //  Remove CSS 2 
    wp_dequeue_style( 'generic styles 2' );
    //  Remove CSS 3
    wp_dequeue_style( 'generic styles 3' );

    //  Remove JS 1
    wp_dequeue_script( 'js 1' );
    //  Remove JS 2
    wp_dequeue_script( 'js 2' );

    // CSS Add Style 1
    wp_enqueue_style( 'css style 1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/new-1.css', array(), '1.0');
    // CSS Add Style 2
    wp_enqueue_style( 'css style 2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/new-2.css', array(), '1.0');
    // CSS Add Style 3
    wp_enqueue_style( 'css style 3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/new-3.css', array(), '1.0');
    // CSS Add Style 4
    wp_enqueue_style( 'css style 4', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/new-4.css', array(), '1.0');
    // CSS Add Style 5
    wp_enqueue_style( 'css style 5', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/new-5.css', array(), '1.0');

    // JS Add Style 1
    wp_enqueue_script( 'js style 1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/new-1.js', array(), '1.0');
    // JS Add Style 2
    wp_enqueue_script( 'js style 2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/new-2.js', array(), '1.0');

}
```

Is my thinking way off or is the above standard WP practice when it comes to creating a template which is dependent on a selection of other CSS/ JS files?

Thanks for all direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using `wp_enqueue_scripts`

You should use a proper hook to enqueue/dequeue your scripts, to ensure that it works flawlessly. A proper plugin/theme uses `wp_enqueue_scripts` to do this, so you should do the same. Wrap your code inside a function, and bind it to this action hook. Also, remember to set the priority to something that makes sure it will override the others.

```
// Setting the priority to 999 to make sure it runs
// after every other script is enqueued
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts', 999);
enqueue_my_scripts () {
    if ( is_page_template( 'specific-template.php' ) ) {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks! So basically is it ok to list all 10 scripts (js/ css) in the same hook?